# Walk an image faster

Tags: php, image

I need to find a particular pixel of an image. Let's say "89 21 24".

I'm using two nested cycles to walk the image:

```
for( $y=$inity; $y<$h; $y++) {
 for( $x=$initx; $x<$w; $x++) {

   $pixel = getpixelat($img,$x,$y);
   if ($pixel == "892124" and getpixelat($img,$x+1,$y) == "1212224") {
       $px = $x; $py = $y;
       break 2;
   }
}
```

I'd like to have a faster algorithm by increasing $y and $x not one by one, instead for example 4 by 4. (Sixteen times faster?)
Of course I need to know exactly the pixels that build 4x4 square.

I would do it like:

```
    if ($pixel == "" and nextpixel...) {
        $px = $x - 1; $py = $y -...;
    }
   //etc.
```

Is there a smarter way to achieve that?

EDIT:

Here's the getpixelat function:

```
function getpixelat($img,$x,$y) {
$rgb = imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;
return $r.$g.$b;
}
```

Comment: What does "89 21 24" represent?

Comment: It represents the RGB of that pixel.

Comment: and where is getpixelat() defined? can't find it in php.net

Comment: Wait a second. I'm editing the question to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the color you are looking for always appears in patches of at least 2x2, or 3x3, or any fixed size, then yes, you can speed up the lookup by incrementing `$x` and `$y` by more than one at each iteration.

For instance, if you know that your patches are always of size at least `KxL`, you can do the following:

```
for( $y=$inity; $y<$h; $y += L) {
    for( $x=$initx; $x<$w; $x += K) {
        $pixel = getpixelat($img,$x,$y);

        if ($pixel == "892124" and getpixelat($img,$x+1,$y) == "1212224") {
            $px = $x; $py = $y;
            break 2;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I'm looking to get the particular position of that pixel. If I find one pixel in the square, then I should do $px = $x - xxx; $py = $y - yyy; How to achieve that without writing 16-25 different lines?

Comment: Well, once you found a pixel that matches, you simply need a second loop of at least KxL steps to go back and find the corner of your patch, assuming all patches are rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

1.) avoide nested loops:

2.) save old value of pixle (calling an function is not that fast)

3.) dont convert colors to string/dont compare strings! (what is 1212224? it is not a Hex-Color )

```
$px=-1;
$py=-1;

$lineW = ($w-$initx);
$lineH = ($h-$inity);
$count = $lineW * $lineH;

$color1 =hexdec ("892124") ;
$color2 =hexdec ("1212224") ;

$x=$initx;
$y=$inity;
$new = imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);

while(true) {
  $x++;
  if ($x>=$w) {
    $x=$initx+1;
    $y++;
    if ($y>=$h) break;
    $new = imagecolorat($img,$x-1,$y);
  }
  $old = $new;
  $new = imagecolorat($img,$x,$y);

  if ($old == $color1 && $new == $color2)
  {
    $px = $x; $py = $y;
    break;
  }
}
```

(code is not tested :-) )

Comment: It gives: Notice: imagecolorat() [function.imagecolorat]: 1280,705 is out of bounds in /Applications/MAMP/www/ocrps.php on line 106

Comment: And remember to set the $color1=hexdec("892124"); and
$color2=hexdec("1212224"); using (your) RRGGBB-Hexvalues!

Comment: maybe it's: if ($x>=$w) { but it still gives Notice: Undefined variable: px

Comment: yeah that's right ($x>=$w) ! I do not know your source... i think the error appears because you dit not create the $px var at the start. This means that the programm did not find the pattern. You have to set the $color1 and $color2 to the right value!